# How do I disable autoplay on Android Remote Spotify SDK

Tags: android, spotify, spotify-app

When I `getPlayerApi().play(<song_uri>)`, the next song plays automatically.  The same thing happens when I call `getPlayerApi().skipNext()` (the song after `.skipNext()` is called, gets played).  I know that autoplay is set to **ON** on my Spotify App, but how can I programmatically disable this?